# How can I echo the status of compilation?

Tags: linux, shell, compilation

I've written a small command to compile every C file in every **directory**, I have:

```
find $1 -type f -name '*.c' -exec sh -c 'gcc  {} -o $(dirname {})/$(basename {} .c)' \;
```

and it compiles everything, but I would like it to display the status of each file being compiled, and display when each one is finished, but I'm really out if ideas.

If anyone could help I would love that!

Comment: what do you mean by status?

Comment: You may want to use [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) to compile your code (notably in parallel with `make -j`), and I suggest passing `-Wall -g` to `gcc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely an academic issue, but using `{}` multiple times in the argument to `find` is not portable.  Similarly, expecting `{}` to expand to the filename when it is not the only string in the argument is not portable.  (That is, the entire argument must be exactly `{}`).  Also, using `gcc` explicitly rather than `make` is probably the wrong approach.  That said, you can simply echo each path that successfully compiles:

```
find $1 -type f -name '*.c' -exec sh -c 'gcc $0 -o $(dirname $0)/$(basename $0.c) &&
    echo $0' {} \;
```

Also, if you can simplify with bash:

```
find $1 -type f -name '*.c' -exec bash -c 'gcc $0 -o ${0%.c}.o && echo $0' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `echo $?` after running `gcc` which will show you its return status. If a file compiles it will be `0`, if it doesn't it will be `1` I think. But there may be different return values for different errors, I'm not sure about this.